# Prove the given results

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $f(x)=a x^{2}+b x+c$ be a quadratic polynomial with integral coefficients, where $a \neq 0$. Show that
> (i) if $f(x)$ is factorisable into linear factors with integral coefficients, then there are integers $d$ and $e$ such that
> $$
> d+e=b \text { and } d e=a c \text {; }
> $$
> and (ii) if integers $d$ and $e$ can be found such that (1) holds, then
> $$
> f(x)=\frac{(a x+d)}{g} \frac{(a x+e)}{a / g},
> $$
> where $g$ is the g.c.d. of $a$ and $d$ and each of the linear factors has integral coefficients.

---

After taking hints from the amswers and comments below, I have tried solving this question. **Please let me know if it's correct or not**. From eyeballfrog's idea, let's assume there are integers $p,q,r,s$ such that
$$
f(x) = ax^2 + b x + c = (px + q)(rx + s) = prx^2 + (ps+qr)x + qs.
$$. By comparing, we get, $a=pr, b=ps+qr, c=qs$. As $ps,qr$ are integers, we can let $ps=d, qr=e$, and from there we get $b=d+e$, and $de=ac$. **Now for the second part**, $\begin{aligned} f(x) &=a x^{2}+b x+c \\ &=\frac{a^{2} x^{2}+a b x+a c}{a} \\ &=\frac{a^{2} x^{2}+a b x+a c}{g \cdot \frac{a}{g}} \\ &=\frac{a^{2} x^{2}+a x(e+d)+a c}{g \cdot \frac{a}{g}} \\ &=\frac{a^{2} x^{2}+a x e+a x d+p q r s}{g \cdot \frac{a}{g}} \\ &=\frac{a^{2} x^{2}+a x e+a x d+d e}{g \cdot \frac{a}{g}} \end{aligned}$ $=\frac{a x(a x+e)+d(a x+e)}{g \cdot \frac{a}{g}}$
$=\frac{(a x+d)}{g} \cdot \frac{(a x+e)}{\frac{a}{g}}$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The next place to go is to expand your expression for $f$ and compare to the original.

Comment: @eyeballfrog won't that just give $\alpha+\beta=-b/a$ and $\alpha \beta=c/a$

Comment: No, it gives $b = a\alpha + a\beta$ and $ac = a^2\alpha \beta$. Show that

Comment: **Hint :** If $ax^2+bx+c$ has integer roots, then $b^2-4ac$ is a square, so $x^2 - bx+ac$ has also integer roots. Can you define $d$ and $e$ accordingly ?

Comment: @eyeballfrog even if I show that, still it's not enough as we don't know if alpha and beta are necessarily integer.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe can you please elaborate it a bit? Are you telling me to think of an quadratic equation with $d,e$ as it's roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (i), we assume that $f$ has linear integer factors. That is, there are integers $p,q,r,s$ such that
$$
f(x) = ax^2 + b x + c = (px + q)(rx + s) = prx^2 + (ps+qr)x + qs.
$$
Can you find the desired integers $d$ and $e$ from here?

For part (ii), multiplying out the product shows it's equal to $f$. So we need to verify that all the coefficients are integers. Since $g =\gcd(a,d)$, $a/g$, $d/g$, and $a/(a/g) = g$ are clearly integers. What about $e/(a/g)$? Hint: you'll need the fact that $a/g$ and $d/g$ have no common factors.

Comment: Why did you assumed the roots to be like $(px+q)(rx+s)$ and not like the traditional way of taking it as in the form $(x-p)(x-q)$ where $p,q$ are the roots?

Comment: Because the question says that the linear factors have integral coefficients, not that the roots themselves are integers. $6x^2 +7x +2$ factors as $(2x+1)(3x+2)$, but neither of its roots are integers.

Comment: Hello, I've edited my original post with my solution with the ideas given by you. Please let me know if it's correct. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

For my proof, I first took the equations as assumptions and proved them to indeed be true.

$ f(x) = a (x-\alpha) (x-\beta) $, now.
$ d + e = b = -a (\alpha + \beta) $, $ de = ac = a^2 \alpha \beta $

Hence, if $ d = -a * \alpha $, $ e = -b * \beta $, they satisfy both equations. And since they add and multiply to become an integer hence they must be integers too.

In the second part of the question the g cancels out, and if you expand the brackets and put the values of $d+e$ and $de$ you will get back $f(x)$.